# How to understand this Joke?

Tags: comprehension

In [Planes, Trains and Automobiles (1987)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planes,_Trains_and_Automobiles), as Del Griffith met his close friend, Gus:

> Gus: Del Griffith! How the hell are you?
>
> Del Griffith: Well, **I'm still a million bucks shy of being a
>   millionaire**.

This is a comedy bit, but what's the joke here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a witty way of saying they have no money. Millionaires are people with at least a million dollars. He's saying that he has a million dollars less than a million dollars — so basically . . . nothing.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand a definition of [*shy*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shy_1):

> 6. *(foll by of) informal*, mainly US and Canadian
>      short (of)".

So he was a million dollars **short of** a million dollars, meaning he had 0 dollars (he was broke).